# media player equalizer

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android media player application. 
Can you anyone tell me please how can I assign the preset value to the songs and play it.

Could you please give me the solution?

The below is the code which am using ,

```
equalizer = new Equalizer(1, audioSessionId);
        equalizer.setEnabled(true);
        equalizer.usePreset(preset);
```

Comment: any1 there to reply me? please

Comment: What do you mean by 'preset'?